# Trouble in identifying the right xpath for instagram scraping

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, extract, instagram

I have been trying my level best to search for xpath  for scraping likes,dates descriptions and all but everytime my program return back with nothing. I have tried changing the headers for example:

```
likes_xpath = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div/button/span'
```

then changed it to:

```
likes_xpath = '//div[@class="likes"]/section/div/div/span/a/span'
```

which on second thought just seems like the wrong way to do it.
I don't understand how to make short xpaths which are not too long so that the program works fine for longer and is much more reliable, I also am unable to figure out the right way to extract something like this.
At this point I am even doubting the code around it

```
    def __lcondition(self, link):
    return '.com/p/' in link.get_attribute('href')

def __get_user(self):
    user = self.__driver.find_element(By.XAPTH, '//*[@id="react-root"]\
      /section/main/div/div[1]/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/a')
    user = user.get_attribute('href').split('/')[-2]
    return user


def filter_links(self, links):
    post_links = []
    for link in links:
        try:
            if '.com/p/' in link.get_attribute('href'):
                post_links.append(link)
        except:
            logger.warning("A https://www.instagram.com/p/ link was not found")
            continue
    return post_links



def __get_subtitles(self,):
    subtitles_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/div/li/div/div/div[2]/span'
    subtitles = self.__driver.find_element(By.XPATH, subtitles_xpath)
    subtitles = subtitles.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    subtitles = BeautifulSoup(subtitles).get_text()
    return subtitles

def __get_image_description(self) -> str:
    images = self.__driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
    post_infos = images[1].get_attribute('alt')

    if len(post_infos) > 0:
        post_infos = post_infos.split("Image may contain: ")
        if len(post_infos) >=2:
            #image
            return post_infos[1]
        else:
            #video
            logger.warning("Description is not available")
            return ''
    else:
        return ''
    
def __get_likes(self):
    likes_xpath = '//div[@class="likes"]/section/div/div/span/a/span'

    likes = self.__driver.find_element(By.XPATH, likes_xpath)
    likes = likes.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    return likes

def __get_views(self):
    '''
    Getting views
    '''
    views_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/span/span'
    views = self.__driver.find_element(By.XPATH, views_xpath)
    views = views.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    return views

def __get_date(self):
    date_xpath = '//time[@class="_aaqe"]/div/a/span/time'
    date = self.__driver.find_element(By.XPATH, date_xpath)
    date = date.get_attribute('datetime')
    return date

def __get_image_data(self, link):
    infos = {}
    infos['date'] = self.__get_date()
    infos['type'] = 'image'
    if len(infos['date']) == 0:
        return None
    infos['user'] = self.__get_user()
    infos['subtitles'] = self.__get_subtitles()
    infos['image_description'] = self.__get_image_description()
    infos['likes'] = self.__get_likes()
    #infos['views'] = None
    infos['link'] = link

    return infos


def __get_video_data(self, link):
    infos = {}
    infos['date'] = self.__get_date()
    infos['type'] = 'video'
    if len(infos['date']) == 0:
        return None
    infos['user'] = self.__get_user()
    infos['subtitles'] = self.__get_subtitles()
    #infos['views'] = self.__get_views()
    infos['likes'] = self.__get_likes()
    infos['link'] = link

    return infos
```

Could someone just help me find the error in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes XPaths are lengthy as we get, but sometimes we can make them shorter for our needs (but look at the HTML hierarchy as well), such as take an example of your provided xpath above:

```
likes_xpath = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div/button/span'
```

we can make it like that as well:

```
likes_xpath = '//*[@id="react-root"]//article/div[3]/section[2]//div/button/span'
```

In order to verify that xpath is correct one. we have countless browser extensions we can use.
I personally use [xpath-helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) and most popular around the market is [selectorshub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorshub/ndgimibanhlabgdgjcpbbndiehljcpfh)..
you can have your pick on that..

Comment: How can check whether the xpath is correct should I enter it in the query section and see if it gives me a result back?

Comment: yes @ARJUNRAMASWAMY

Comment: Can you tick the answer, if solution is working..